# How to configure custom error page for node application when runing port not available?

Tags: node.js

I have one problem like when am executing `gulp` or `npm start` command to start my Node application, it taking around 2 minute to complete. But as client requirement for this 2 minute when they hitting url to access application they should get custom error page. How to configure custom error page for this senario?

Comment: Can you please add code snippet of what you're doing?

Comment: Am trying to run 1 more node app which will check Target application available or not, if available redirect to target application, else refresh page . but this one not acceptable.

Comment: How you're checking the availability of the target application?

Comment: var express = require('express'); var app = express(); var request = require('request');
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/views'));
app.get('*', function(req, res){
request.get({url: 'https://localhost:8089',agentOptions: { rejectUnauthorized: false }
}, function (error, response, body) { 
if(error){
res.redirect('http://localhost:8011/#/ErrorPage.html');
//res.write('Please wait, Server getting ready to work...!!!');    
res.end();  }else{
res.writeHead( 301,{Location: 'https://localhost:8085'} );
res.end();
}
});
});
app.listen(8011);

Comment: Why don't you update that code into the question?

Comment: that is not related to my senario, and not correct one.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to redirect to other URL, you need to add the "http" in the res.redirect, please look at the below code snippet:

```
app.get('*', function (req, res) {
  request.get({
    url: 'localhost:8089',
    agentOptions: {
      rejectUnauthorized: false
    }
  }, function (error, response, body) {
    if (error) {
      res.redirect('http://www.google.com/')
    }
  });
});
```

In your case, it'll be:

```
res.redirect('http://localhost:8011/#/ErrorPage.html')
```